# Scrolling down an awt.List

Tags: java, list, scroll

As from subject, I have an `awt.List` object. When I add something to the list I would like to scroll it down to show the last inserted object.

For instance:

```
myList.add("sometext");
myList.select(myList.getItemCount()-1);
myList.showSelectedItem(); // Or something like that
```

The [documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/List.html) does not seem to list any method that does something like that, can anybody help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that this is possible (explicitly).  In my experience I have written an app for a Windows Mobile device using AWT and when I used one JVM calling `myList.select(myList.getItemCount()-1);` was enough to get it to scroll to that item, but as soon as I switched to another JVM it did not do it.  So it is implementation dependent but I think there is no requirement in the specification that says that a List field should do this.

My workaround was simply to reverse the List, so that new items were added at the top.  Understandably this is not ideal for all situtations, but in my case it was fine.

Comment: Thank you, I feared the answer would sound like that... :(
I'll just have to use your workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I use the makeVisible(index) call where index is the index of the item that is selected. This scrolls the listbox down until the selected item is visible.  I'm using JDK 1.6.0_65 on Mac OSX 10.8.